# Angular JS Verify CSRF Token in POST Request

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I am using AngularJS with Rails. I have the following request which updates users in bulk.

```
 $http{
    method: 'POST',
    url: $scope.update_url,
    params: {selected_ids: userIds}
 }
```

This cannot be a 'GET' request due to restrictions in the length of the URL (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

But for 'POST' request, we need to have a CSRF authenticity token in the header.

How can we set the CSRF Token to the post request header?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can set http headers as explained in the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service.

You can set it up globally:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['My-Header']='value'   (or)
$http.defaults.headers.post['My-Header']='value';
```

or for a single request:

```
$http({
   headers: {
      'My-Header': 'value'
   }  
});
```

Here is an important quote from [Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http):

> Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection XSRF is a technique by
>   which an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data. Angular
>   provides following mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR
>   requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie called
>   XSRF-TOKEN and sets it as the HTTP header X-XSRF-TOKEN. Since only
>   JavaScript that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server
>   can be assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your
>   domain.
>
> To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a
>   JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on first HTTP GET
>   request. On subsequent non-GET requests the server can verify that the
>   cookie matches X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header, and therefore be sure that
>   only JavaScript running on your domain could have read the token. The
>   token must be unique for each user and must be verifiable by the
>   server (to prevent the JavaScript making up its own tokens). We
>   recommend that the token is a digest of your site's authentication
>   cookie with salt for added security.

Comment: Thanks asgoth! Is this the right way for having a post request with CSRF-Token being set? Or should I create a hidden form and submit the form with studentIds on ng-click() ? But in that case, how can i get the response data? Thanks again!

Comment: I've added a quote from angular itself.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why this solution is consistent with Angular's documentation. The docs state that you need to set a cookie but you appear to be setting the header manually.

Comment: @asgoth I am not sure how this counters CSRF. I thought that CSRF worked because a call to the same domain from another browser page would resend the cookie associated with that domain. If we placed the token in the cookie wouldn't that render that check useless?

Comment: @RevNoah The code samples at the top are generic examples of how to set headers on the $http service. If the cookie token is set angular will set the header automatically.

Comment: @uriDium It counters CSRF because the cookie token isn't the same as a request header.  The header is called X-XSRF-TOKEN. Even though the cookie is sent with all requests it just has a token called XSRF-TOKEN, which the server doesn't care about.  The only way to copy the cookie token to the request header is if you can read the cookie, which pages on another domain can't do.  That's why this method works.

Comment: Instead of using a cookie to notify Angular, would it be just as secure to define a CONSTANT and inject that into Angular?

Comment: For instance, in my starting page (I use PHP as server side language), I set an Angular constant like this: <script>
    angular.module("app").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?=$csrf_token;?>'); 
</script>

Comment: .. then in Angular I inject CSRF_TOKEN in app.run() and set the header: $http.defaults.headers.common['CSRF_TOKEN'] = CSRF_TOKEN  ... also, I set it for all requests, POST/GET.. just make sure your GET query doesn't surpass 1024 chars

Comment: I suggest using `$http.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = yourtoken` to have the token in all requests and not just in POST.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering how to actually set a XSRF-TOKEN cookie value in Rails this answer has an implementation [Rails CSRF Protection + Angular.js: protect_from_forgery makes me to log out on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734243/rails-csrf-protection-angular-js-protect-from-forgery-makes-me-to-log-out-on)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue and adding the gem [angular_rails_js](https://github.com/jsanders/angular_rails_csrf) solved it. To my understanding it creates for every rails controller a cookie with the rails CSRF-TOKEN that will be catch (default $http behaviour) by angular $http.