# How to send csrf_token() inside AngularJS form using Laravel API?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, csrf-protection

I am trying to build an angular + laravel rest application. I can get the views of my database. When I try to add new items. I get `500 error` telling me mismatch  csrf token. 
My form layout is :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="addItem()">

  <input type="text" ng-model="itemEntry" placeholder="Type and hit Enter to add item">
</form>
```

This is how I try to add item to database :

```
$scope.addItem = function(CSRF_TOKEN) {
    $http.post('/shop', { text: $scope.itemEntry, csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN} ).success(function(data, status) {
        if(data) {
            var last = _.last($scope.items);
            _token = CSRF_TOKEN;
            $scope.items.push({text: $scope.itemEntry, bought: false, id: (last.id + 1) });
            $scope.itemEntry = '';
            console.log($scope.items);
        } else {
            console.log('There was a problem. Status: ' + status + '; Data: ' + data);
        }
    }).error(function(data, status) {
            console.log('status: ' + status);
        });

}
```

Here is my filter that I use for my application:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

In my blade views I use this and it works :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

How can I send the csrf_token when I use html forms?

Thanks

Edit 1 : 
Adding header to post request like this does not give errors.

```
  $http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : '/shop',
    data    :  $scope.itemEntry,  // pass in data as strings
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }   
  });
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An option will be to inject the CSRF token as a constant. Append the following in your head tag:

```html
<script>
  angular.module("app").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '{{ csrf_token() }}');
</script>
```

Then in your module methods it can be injected when needed.

```js
app.factory("FooService", function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
    console.log(CSRF_TOKEN);
};
```

Maybe you will be interested of peeking at the source code of this [sample Laravel + AngularJS project](https://github.com/davemo/end-to-end-with-angularjs).

Comment: Hello , I added script in the head. I injected CSRF_TOKEN . How do I add it inside form ? I edited my code btw.

Comment: I still could not manage it , I read the code end-to-end. I edited  $scope.addItem . Can you give a look ?

Answer (score 23):

the accepted solution by Rubens Mariuzzo works, however I think that I have found an alternative solution which I think is better.

This way you don't have to pass data from the html script into your angularjs app and there is a better separation of concerns. E.g. This allows you to have your Laravel APP as just an API.

My solution involves getting the CSRF token via an api request and setting this value as a constant.

Further, instead of injecting the CSRF token when needed, you set the token in a default header which would get checked by the server upon any API http request.

Example shows laravel, however any serious framework should be able to offer something similar.

CSRF Route in LARAVEL:

```
// Returns the csrf token for the current visitor's session.
Route::get('api/csrf', function() {
    return Session::token();
});
```

Protecting Routes with the `before => 'api.csrf'` Filter

```
// Before making the declared routes available, run them through the api.csrf filter
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'api.csrf'), function() {
Route::resource('test1', 'Api\V1\Test1Controller');
Route::resource('test2', 'Api\V1\Test2Controller');
});
```

The `api.csrf` filter

```
// If the session token is not the same as the the request header X-Csrf-Token, then return a 400 error.
Route::filter('api.csrf', function($route, $request)
{
if (Session::token() != $request->header('X-Csrf-Token') )
{
    return Response::json('CSRF does not match', 400);
}
});
```

The AngularJS stuff put this in app.js:

Blocking Version:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/api/csrf", false);
xhReq.send(null);

app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", xhReq.responseText);

app.run(['$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {    
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
}]);
```

Non-Blocking Version

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/api/csrf", true);

xhReq.onload = function(e) {
  if (xhReq.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhReq.status === 200) {
      app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", xhReq.responseText);

      app.run(['$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
      }]);
    }
  }
};

xhReq.send(null);
```

Now the CSRF_TOKEN constant is injected as a header in ALL http requests from the AngularJS app and ALL API routes are protected.

Comment: Hey I added one more alternative for that solution. Can you check and make your comment if it is a nice solution also ?

Comment: @ytsejam - I don't understand how specifying the content-type in the header is an alternative solution for getting a CSRF token from the server to the AngularJS app.

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application

Comment: @Gravy are you serving your angular app from the same domain?  I currently have my api at api.example.com and angular being served from example.com so I am having problems with the session being made since it is considered cross origin.

Comment: @ddelnano - Sorry for late reply - I've been on holiday. You should be able to do this by setting the domain of your javascript app to the same as your main web application e.g. for `example.com`, -  `document.domain = 'example.com';`.

Comment: This doesn't work for a REST api, the token is not going to be the same.

Comment: @Gravy Do I need to create the `filter.php` file also in Laravel 5 or I can use come inbuilt library class to achieve this? If i have to add it then what would be the location? `app/` in L5 are the DB model classes,so I dont want something there.Please suggest.

Answer (score 23):

If you use Laravel 5, **no need** to add CSRF token to Angular http headers.

Laravel 5 with Angular do this automatically for you.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token

Comment: awesome. completely missed this

Answer (score 7):

I think my solution is less pain and much more flexible, especially it thinks testing your App on Karma.

Firstly add this code your master view

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

We have saved csrf token into html content without adding route.

Now we protect all requests of AngularJs App by CSRF token

```
/**
 * 
 * when it thinks testing your app unit test with Karma,
 * this solution was better than getting token via AJAX.
 * Because low-level Ajax request correctly doesn't work on Karma
 * 
 * Helper idea to me :
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734243/rails-csrf-protection-angular-js-protect-from-forgery-makes-me-to-log-out-on/15761835#15761835 
 * 
 */
var csrftoken =  (function() {
    // not need Jquery for doing that
    var metas = window.document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

    // finding one has csrf token 
    for(var i=0 ; i < metas.length ; i++) {

        if ( metas[i].name === "csrf-token") {

            return  metas[i].content;       
        }
    }  

})();

// adding constant into our app

yourAngularApp.constant('CSRF_TOKEN', csrftoken);
```

We need to setup default http headers for Angular. Let's add our csrf token to Angular's headers

```
/*
 * App Configs
 */
blog.config(['$httpProvider', 'CSRF_TOKEN',

  function($httpProvider, CSRF_TOKEN) {


    /**
     * adds CSRF token to header
     */
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = CSRF_TOKEN;

 }]);
```

Finally we have to need new filter for this changes on side of laravel..

```
Route::filter('csrfInHeader', function($route, $request) {

    if (Session::token() !== (string) $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN') ) {

        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

    }
});
```

"csrfInHeader" filter will check all http request by angular app. You are not need adding csrf token  to every each request. Plus if you test your app by Karma, you will not effort to getting csrf token on testing..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it as

```
Route::get('/getToken','Controller@getToken');
```

> In your web or api.php file

In Controller

```
public function getToken(){

          return csrf_token();

    }
```

> Place this code

In Angular app

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8000/getToken")
  .then(function(response) {
    alert(response.data)
  });
```

> Safe way to get csrf_token()