# laravel 4: why is Request::header() not getting the specified header?

Tags: php, angularjs, header, laravel, csrf-protection

I'm trying to get a header value with:

`Request::header('csrf_token')`

though, my firebug says in the headers that I have the csrf_token set to `baMDpF0yrfRerkdihFack1Sa9cchUk8qBzm0hK0C`. In fact, I can get that `csrf_token` instead with a native php code:

`getallheaders()['csrf_token']`

Now the question is am I doing my XSRF-protection right?  or maybe there is a flaw in that php code I did, that I really have to use buggy laravel 4 function

`Request::header('csrf_token')`

which returns nothing but blank. And I just missed something. maybe in my Laravel 4 configurations, etc?

P.S: I am using AngularJS, but maybe it does not matter what clientside I use. I have this link as my guide: [How to send csrf_token() inside AngularJS form using Laravel API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336699/how-to-send-csrf-token-inside-angularjs-form-using-laravel-api)

Comment: Allow me a little question back: Why do you expect that `Request::header('csrf_token')` returns that header value in the first place? Just because of the name of the class-method? Have you looked into the source of that method what it actually does?

Comment: @hakre: thanks for that comment and idea. Source code you say? hmm I dont find it easy and intuitive to follow. So what must be the appropriate function to use then? if not Request::header(); like how Content-type was retrieve in laravel four's documentation; Request::header('Content-Type');

Comment: I just wanted to find out about why you have choosen that code. As your comment shows, some kind of minimal understanding seems missing which is an off-topic criteria for this Q&A website as you don't even expect the code in question to work and reproduce the issue. I suggest you ask around in the Laravel 4 forums instead.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: alright, ill see it then. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

I solved the problem by removing the underscore '_' in csrf_token so it would be crsftoken instead.

```
Request::header('csrf_token'); // Not working

Request::header('csrftoken'); // Working!
```

Comment: apparently Laravel has a problem with header names that has underscores ?

Comment: this solved my problem as well. i would have never guessed this to be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

Laravel is removing headers with an underscore in the name when retrieving them with the `Request::header()` method. Additionally, all header names are converted to lower case in the `Request::header()` method.

**Short Solution**

On the frontend, replace all underscores in header names with dashes. `csrf_token` becomes `csrf-token`

**Long Solution**

Add the Laravel CSRF token as an Angular constant on your main page / layout.

```
<script>
    angular.module("myApp").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"); 
</script>
```

Add the token as a default header for all your requests in Angular.

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function($http, CSRF_TOKEN){
    $http.defaults.headers.common["csrf-token"] = CSRF_TOKEN;
})
```

Have your `csrf` filter in Laravel check for a match in the headers rather than an input.

```
/**
 * Check that our session token matches the CSRF request header token.
 *
 * @return json
 */
Route::filter("csrf", function() {
    if (Session::token() !== Request::header("csrf-token")) {
        return Response::json(array(
            "error" => array(
                "code"    => "403",
                "message" => "Ah ah ah, you didn't say the magic word.",
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Request::header()` is indeed used for the [retrieval of headers](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information), but check where the token is being set.. the CSRF token should be [placed into the session by Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/html#csrf-protection), and then it can be accessed through the **[`Session::token()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Session.Store.html#_token)** method.

If you look at the HTML generated through calls to the `Form::` class, you'll see a hidden element called `_token`, which should then be compared to the token in the session.  You can access that using `Input::get('_token')`, as with any other incoming GET or POST variable.

...However, all this shouldn't really be necessary, as it can be managed easily through the pre-defined `CSRF` filter in `filters.php`, just [add that filter to the desired route or route group](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) and you'll be protected, without having to get into the details of it.

Comment: Hello. I cannot use the Form:: class of laravel since my forms are generated by Angularjs as my frontend. But that's not a problem. In my SPA i was able to get that token by `<?php echo csrf_token() ?>` so I used that value in my frontend to make a header csrf_token which will then be read and matched to Session::token() (which does fine) by laravel4, though I can get that by getallheaders()['csrf_token']; I was just wondering why Request::header('csrf_token') returns empty

Comment: ah, apologies, missed that part!  I think Hakre was right, best to take up on the laravel forums!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem there is that in the following answer at [How to send csrf_token() inside AngularJS form using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336699/how-to-send-csrf-token-inside-angularjs-form-using-laravel-api) that you used, the csrf_token is not sent in the header of your XMLHttpRequest but in the form it self.

You need then to filter it in your laravel backend as a regular Input field. See below for a working example :

```
Route::filter('csrf_json', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('csrf_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use headers in Angular, you would rather write something like :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = TOKEN;
```

In order to aplly a new header to your XMLHttpRequests. Then it is easily catchable even with raw php such as :

```
$aHeaders = getallheaders();
if (Session::token() != $aHeaders['authorization']) etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the Symfony Request object, which is extended in the Laravel framework. See this github thread

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1655#issuecomment-20595277

The solution in your case would be to set the header name to HTTP_CSRF_TOKEN or HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN if you like prefixing X to your custom http headers.