# Laravel in Apache getting header value

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have the following piece of code in Laravel BaseController. I want to protect all my api resources with an `Authorization` header with a token.

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->beforeFilter('@getUserFromToken');
  }

  public function getUserFromToken($route, $request)
  {
    $accessToken = Request::header('Authorization');
    if(!empty($accessToken)){
      $this->currentUser = User::findByToken($accessToken);
    }else{
      return Request::header('Authorization'); //THE PROBLEM
      return Response::json(['error'=>'Not authorized. Access token needed in Header.Authorization'], 403);
    }
  }
```

Here is my .htaccess if that's relevant.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So if I have the marked problem line, Apache will read everything perfectly. And I will get my responses back and not getting the `403`. However, if I don't have that line, I will get `403` error with my custom error message. WHY? Obviously I am using the same code `$this->currentUser = User::findByToken($accessToken);`, why by leaving the marked line I'll be able to get the header? Is there a redirect happening behind the scene that sets the `Authorization` header somehow only the second time? Is there a setting that I missed for apache to pick up the header the first time?

UPDATE:
I guess my question is: if I just `return Response::json(['error'=>'Not authorized. Access token needed in Header.Authorization'], 403);`, I will always get this error json. And my $accessToken will always be empty. Why?

MORE UPDATE:
Looks like I shouldn't reuse `Authorization` Header? I tried:

```
$accessToken = Request::header('Custom-Token');
if(!empty($accessToken)){
  $this->currentUser = User::findByToken($accessToken);
}else{
  return Response::json(['error'=>'Not authorized. Access token needed in Header.Authorization'], 403);
}
```

And this time I'm able to get the real token. My question still stands then, why can I return the "magical" header and suddenly get it in Laravel?

This related question didn't answer it, but pointed me to the right direction: [laravel 4: why is Request::header() not getting the specified header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585322/laravel-4-why-is-requestheader-not-getting-the-specified-header)

One more thing: the `Authorization` header does work without the magic return if I serve use `php artisan serve`, which uses php dev server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a Laravel & Apache problem, this line in public/.htaccess fixed it for me:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

The fix is from https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/54

Comment: You are an angel. I banged my head for endless hours and could not figure out what went wrong. If it weren't for this answer I would go on using the token in the URL params which is not a clean approach if you ask me. I have raised a bounty and will award it to you as soon as Stack Overflow lets me. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @Rohan. Glad it also helped you. Don't worry about the bounty. Your comment is reward in itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two returns in PHP:

```
return Request::header();
return Response::json();
```

So in your code, only the header will return, and your code will exit.

I think this will work

```
return Response::json(['error'=>'Not authorized. Access token needed in Header.Authorization'], 403)->header('Authorization');
```

If not - this definetely will:

```
$response = Response::json(['error'=>'Not authorized. Access token needed in Header.Authorization'], 403);
$response->header('Authorization');
return $response;
```

Comment: I know. I'm only putting that code there while debugging, and somehow found a fix. I would like to do `return Response::json(['error'=>'Not authorized. Access token needed in Header.Authorization'], 403);` But my question is really why the `Authorization` value is empty when it came through.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking - please expand on your question with more information.

Comment: Not really. Why do you think $accessToken will be magically filled if you return a JSON error?

Comment: I don't know why. That's the problem. :) I'm wondering if it's something with apache or my code. Anyway, if I do `return 'Your Header.Authorization is: '. $accessToken;`, it will always return `Your Header.Authorization is: `. If I do that "magic" return, I will get the results that I want. But I don't want the "magic" return all the time, only when I really truly don't have a Header.Authorization set.