# Laravel Sanctum SPA Auth - Unauthenticated After Successfully Login

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have an application with Laravel and Vue.js for the separate folder which one is for the backend and another is the frontend and I have successfully configured all following the Laravel sanctum documentation and also protecting the route API and I am able to successfully log in and register but after successfully Login it's showing me "Unauthenticated " when I try to fetch the authenticated user. I am using localhost as a default. can anyone give me some suggestions

.env file I have also set it

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel sanctum unauthenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843137/laravel-sanctum-unauthenticated)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have found the solution

#`localhost`

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080,127.0.0.1:8080,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

`localhost:8080` for frontend server the port might be changing sometimes like `localhost:8081` `localhost:3000` so make sure you put the correct URL

#`Live Server`

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=*.yourdomain.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=.yourdomain.com
```

I have also figure out sometimes I was right but the Laravel cache gives me the wrong result so you have to clean the Laravel cache and also browser cache. you can follow the below code to make a route function in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {

   Artisan::call('cache:clear');
   Artisan::call('config:clear');
   Artisan::call('config:cache');
   Artisan::call('view:clear');

   return "Cleared!";

});
```

Hope it will works

Thanks