# Laravel Sanctum authentication failure on live server even after successful authentication

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

Completed the application setup with a complete authentication feature using sanctum and it is working fine on the local machine.
But when I uploaded the application on the live server, the authentication returns the token too. But when the routes under sanctum middleware are accessed, it just returns an unauthenticated error.

I also changed the `.env` files as:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=
SESSION_DOMAIN=
```

But still it is not working. Kindly help on this issue.

Comment: This may Help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418443/15648920

Comment: I tried this but got no help. This is helpful if it happens in localhost. I am facing it on live server.

Comment: are you working with an api or web?

Comment: I am working on API

Comment: Laravel Sanctum doesn't appear to support wildcard domains for the SPA.

Comment: can you update the `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=
SESSION_DOMAIN=`  for both production and local

Comment: I think the issue is there.. since its working fine in local

Comment: What to change in SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS= SESSION_DOMAIN= can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Actually I am not using any domain. This application is running on host/port no. No domain is pointed yet. What to do. Any Ideas ?