# How to declare SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS env for postman or insomnia

Tags: laravel, postman, single-page-application, insomnia

I build a spa with [laravel-sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication)
But I have problem when authenticate.
Because authenticate via laravel-sanctum using CSRF (not token) needs to declare SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS first. But postman or insomnia send request on a random port. So I can't authenticate

Can anyone give me a hint or something?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843137/laravel-sanctum-unauthenticated ?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 tks you. But I have problem with postman It send reuqest in dynamic port => I canot configure stateful domains to authenticate via X-CSRF (not token). And I have no problem in my front end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$domain = $request->headers->get('referer') ?: $request->headers->get('origin');
```

This is a snippet in
`\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class`

=> NEED set header `referer` or `origin` to a given domain and declare this domain to `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` config.