# React - Laravel Sanctum suddenly starts to return Token Mismatch

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-sanctum

The problem is that Laravel/Sanctum starts to respond with 419 Unknown Status (CSRF Token Mismatch) errors. This happens when logged in and even logging out. Even in incognito mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsiYd.png)

Comment: What url are you accessing in the browser?

Comment: SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843137/laravel-sanctum-unauthenticated/64418443#64418443 should be helpful