# Laravel JWT always respond 401, Shared hosting, Apache

Tags: laravel, apache, jwt

Laravel $request->bearerToken(); respond null. Laravel Doesn't see authorization header in apache web server. My code is here:

JwtMiddleware:

```
    $jwt = $request->bearerToken();
  
    if (!$jwt) {
        Log::warning('json web token not found');
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 401,
            'reply' => 'Unauthenticated!'
        ], 401);
    }
```

I added bearer token to request in postman but it doesn't work.

Also code is working in local machine with artisan serve but it doesn't work on server.

Comment: How about checking network packet in your chrome dev tools?  Did it also missing header?

Comment: ı check devtools, sending on request headers, not exist in middleware or controller.

Comment: It might be caused your web server policy setting. 
 this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35035169/5865556 will be helpful.

Comment: I tried this solution for .htaccess file but it doesn't fix

Comment: if move routes from api.php to web.php, this problem was fix. I think it can be because of api guard, it is working for web guard.