# Laravel 5 Internal Server Error 500 and TokenMismatchException to update the database using AngularsJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I keep getting an internal Server Error 500 (TokenMismatchException) when doing an update from angularjs.

angular function:

```
  vm.eventSaved = function(event) { 

       $http.put('/api/events/' + event.eventid, vm.event).success(function(eventsuccess){
       }).error(function(err){             });

  };
```

Values passed through  vm.event

```
{
    "events": 
    {
        "_token": "xGD7kTETgmBytf8exwIUYHYEC6lKcPek9NCuz6Xh",
        "eventid": "37",
        "title": "Events",
        "type": "info",
        "startsAt": "2015-08-15T10:46:00+00:00",
        "endsAt": "2015-08-15T11:46:00+00:00",
        "draggable": "true",
        "resizable": "true"
    }
}
```

Laravel controller function:

```
public function update($id, AppointmentsRequest $request)
{       
    $appointments = Appointment::findOrFail($id);
    $appointments->update($request->all());

    return Response::json(array('success'=>true));
}
```

Is there something I should add to my Laravel controller to handle this? I do practically the same thing with a "delete" and I don't get this error.

Comment: Hmm, they say they should add a CSRF header when performing ajax calls, have you tried adding the the ```X-CSRF-TOKEN``` header like described in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token)?

Comment: With the Httprequester tool in FF, I see that a cookie is set ( XSRF-TOKEN=....) when I do a GET , but when I do a PUT I don't see if the cookie is gone

Comment: Ok, I think using ,{withCredentials: true} in my $http.put will help

Comment: I am not sure how reliable this would be. Check out [the answer I just found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18338635/1125161). It says that you need to add a constant to your angular app, but then again, the next answer reads from the documentation that if you are using Laravel 5, you shouldn't have any worries with all this

Comment: and it is in fact working fine with Laravel 5.. the problem was .. me. I wasn't looking at the right place for the error. Sorry guys, thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel 5 the crsf token cookie is set automatically when using front end frameworks such as Angular. You should consider removing `"_token": "xGD7kTETgmBytf8exwIUYHYEC6lKcPek9NCuz6Xh"` from the input been sent to the controller. Then try it out.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the Httprequester tool in FF (for simulating a PUT) and thus, I was not able to reproduce the problem (because no token existed), so Laravel gave me the Internal Server Error 500 (TokenMismatchException). I noticed that when looking at the Laravel logs and seeing that my "real" error was not related to the token.