# prefilter for angular $http request like my ajax example

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, model-view-controller

I set up an ajax prefilter for CSRF protection.. This uses the MVC @Html.AntiForgeryToken() and automatically appends it to each .ajax request.

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.type.toUpperCase() === "POST") {
            // We need to add the verificationToken to all POSTs
            var token = $("input[name^=__RequestVerificationToken]").first();
            if (!token.length) return;

            var tokenName = token.attr("name");

            // If the data is JSON, then we need to put the token in the QueryString:
            if (options.contentType.indexOf('application/json') === 0) {
                // Add the token to the URL, because we can't add it to the JSON data:
                options.url += ((options.url.indexOf("?") === -1) ? "?" : "&") + token.serialize();
            } else if (typeof options.data === 'string' && options.data.indexOf(tokenName) === -1) {
                // Append to the data string:
                options.data += (options.data ? "&" : "") + token.serialize();
            }
        }
    });
```

now, I need to do the same thing for angular $http requests but am seriously struggling. Any tips?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: That looks like an interceptor. Check the $http documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: AngularJS does this out of the box. No need to implement your own interceptor https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http look for Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection

Answer (score 0):

Something like this from one of my previous answers?

[How to send csrf_token() inside AngularJS form using Laravel API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336699/how-to-send-csrf-token-inside-angularjs-form-using-laravel-api/23760366#23760366)

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "//" + window.location.hostname + "/api/csrf", true);

xhReq.onload = function(e) {
  if (xhReq.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhReq.status === 200) {
      app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", xhReq.responseText);

      app.run(['$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
      }]);
    }
  }
};

xhReq.send(null);
```