# How to recieve csrf token from laravel rotues to angularjs meta tag

Tags: angularjs, authentication, laravel-5.3, csrf-protection

I had researched over it but I am unable get my solution.
I have separate angularjs ande laravel folders. and I am connecting them through API. I am not using laravel blade temple-ting engine for this.

I have set

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in my index.html page.

while I console the thing:

```
console.log($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
```

I got as `{{ csrf() }}`

I followed some of the SO question to solve this issue but I am not getting it. Here is the link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336699/how-to-send-csrf-token-inside-angularjs-form-using-laravel-api)

I am interested in using this way auth :[image]
But not getting how?
I am new to this, that why facing problem in this.Please Help me for this.