# spring boot angular js http:/localhost:8080/logout 403 forbidden error

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I couldn't solve this issue.

I try to athentication login logout example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii). Login is work properly but when I try to logout, browser gives NetworkError : 403 forbidden localhost:8080/logout is forbidden.

In my opinion I should add token header every request from ui side.But I don't know and find how can I do that?

here is the browser developer tools message :

> POST  403 
>    {"timestamp":1501570024381,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was
>    found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.","path":"/helpdesk/logout"}

here is my angular logout function:

```
 $scope.logout = function() {
    $http.post('logout',{}).success(function() {
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      $location.path("/home");
    }).error(function(data) {
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    });
  }
```

here is my SpringSecurityConfig configure method:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html","/pages/**","/","/webjars/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false)
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

}
```

How can I solve this? How can I add token header to all request? Could you help me please?

Comment: You don't need to do this explicitly  `$rootScope.authenticated = false;`  or `$location.path("/home");`. Your Configurtion should be sufficient to logout the user, you should be able to perform simple post request to logout. However, it would be helpful to know SpringSec version you are using. You might want to include additional headers to your post request.

Comment: I have to set $rootscope.authenticated = false because some view hidden or display state of this param. I"ll try this solution if it'll work I tey different way for this. Thank you.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. I editted the question.

Comment: Btw, I checked your link to the tutorial you are following. At first glance they are describing how to handle `CSRF` tokens. My answer might be useless

Comment: You need to send the csrf token in your call to the spring controller because thats how Spring security works. Based on these csrf tokens only the calls are verified and  authorized.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Thank you for your interesting. I noticed that but how can I do that? I research but I couldn't achieve. Do you no,,know any sample for this?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18338635/3094731).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45455423/5707108 please check this @AbdullahKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue:

Firstly I find [this sample](http://shermandigital.com/blog/csrf-protection-with-angularjs-and-spring/) when I research on goole.

After that I applied same interceptor my app like this :

```
app.factory('CsrfTokenInterceptorService', ['$q',
function CsrfTokenInterceptorService($q) {

    // Private constants.
    var CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN',
        HTTP_TYPES_TO_ADD_TOKEN = ['DELETE', 'POST', 'PUT'];

    // Private properties.
    var token;

    // Public interface.
    var service = {
        response: onSuccess,
        responseError: onFailure,
        request: onRequest,
    };

    return service;

    // Private functions.
    function onFailure(response) {
        if (response.status === 403) {
            console.log('Request forbidden. Ensure CSRF token is sent for non-idempotent requests.');
        }

        return $q.reject(response);
    }

    function onRequest(config) {
        if (HTTP_TYPES_TO_ADD_TOKEN.indexOf(config.method.toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
            config.headers[CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER] = token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    function onSuccess(response) {
        var newToken = response.headers(CSRF_TOKEN_HEADER);

        if (newToken) {
            token = newToken;
        }

        return response;
    }
}]);
```

and added to app.config method this :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('CsrfTokenInterceptorService');
```

But now I have an another problem. Browser start to open custom authentication popup. I have to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

`CSRF` token would be checked for all the `post`requests by SpringSec. Thus, you can either include it everytime, or disable it. XML config would look something like this:

```
<http ...... >

  <!-- ... -->
  <csrf disabled="true"/>

</http>
```

Or simply add the following in your `config`:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html","/pages/**","/","/webjars/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false)
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

}
```

This way you don't need to care about its inclusion. For proper handling of `CSRF Tokens` take a look at [Spring Security’s Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) support.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html).

P.S. let me know in case it doesn't help or at least point you to the right direction.

Comment: thank you for your interesting. Well, Do we have to disable csrf? I mean we have to secure sessions on ours application am I right? If I got correctly, I send csrf tokens as header all request from angular js. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with  angular, but I would guess that the link to Spring Sec support and tutorial that you are following should give you some insight. Best of luck :)

Comment: please check stackoverflow.com/a/45455423/5707108 this.