# form_tag or csrf_token in slim(erb) templates for angularjs in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using slime templates for angularjs in rails project. 
Like in this link https://coderwall.com/p/cthwfq

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end

Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)
```

But now I have a problem with form_tag in templates. Or with csrf token (protect_from_forgery error) in normal html not ajax forms in templates. 
Because in templates I can't use

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
```

because form_authenticity_token can't find.
I try include additional rails modules in Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval, but this is looking very strange and doesn't work.

Comment: I'd advise you to follow a different path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734243/rails-csrf-protection-angular-js-protect-from-forgery-makes-me-to-log-out-on