# Unauthorize error on password update Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I'm  working on a rails api and using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for the authentication, when I try to update password by hitting the `/auth/password` with put request it responsds with error 401 i.e. unauthorized. My server logs show me this

> Started PUT "/auth/password"  Processing by
>   DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController#update as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
>   Can't verify CSRF token authenticity Completed 401 Unauthorized in

**routes.rb**

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth' ,:controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth'  }
```

**view.html (angularjs)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 que">
           <img src="./uploads/img/web-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
       </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 reset-pas">
            <form  name="update_pass" ng-submit="updatePassword_controller()" role="form" class="lost_reset_password">
                <p class="error_msg" ng-show="update_pass.password_confirmation.$error.passwordVerify"> 
                    Passwords are not equal!
                </p>
            <label>New password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"  ng-minlength="8"  ng-model="updatePasswordForm.password" required="required" class="form-control">
            <span>Minimum 8 Charachters</span>
    <br>
            <label>Re-enter new password</label>

            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation"  ng-minlength="8"  ng-model="updatePasswordForm.password_confirmation" required="required" class="form-control"  password-verify="updatePasswordForm.password" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="reset-submit">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.updatePassword_controller = function() {

  $auth.updatePassword($scope.updatePasswordForm)
    .then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp)
      $location.path('/')
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp)
    });
};
```

**Update**
**Note**
I'm facing this issue only for password update

**Update**

I installed `gem 'angular_rails_csrf'` Now it's giving only the `authorization error` not the `csrf attack error`

Comment: how are you making the request? you are missing the CSRF (authenticity_token) in your request.

Comment: @zekus dear how can i add that ?

Comment: this question was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734243/rails-csrf-protection-angular-js-protect-from-forgery-makes-me-to-log-out-on/15761835#15761835 also check this http://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-set-csrf-with-angularjs-and-rails. that should solve I guess.

Comment: @zekus no dear , still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply made a condition in applicationcontroller.rb like below and it worked out . The main idea is simply to override the functionality of Devise

```
        if params[:controller] == "devise_token_auth/passwords" && params[:action] == "update"

              uri               = URI.parse(request.headers.env['HTTP_REFERER'])
              query_params      = CGI.parse(uri.query)
              email             = query_params['uid'].first
              user              = User.find_by_email(email)
              user.password     = params[:password]
              user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]

              if user.save
                    render json: {message: 'Password Updated successfully', status: 200}                        
              else
                    render json: {message: 'Password Could not changed , Please contact to support Team', status: 401}
              end
        end
```

Although it's not the proper solution but i couldn't think of anyother one . So please bear with me .In it we're fetching email from url

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rails `form_tag` or `form_for` helpers. They add will add a hidden field for the XCSRF token:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 que">
           <img src="./uploads/img/web-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
       </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 reset-pas">
            <%= form_tag "#", { "ng-submit" => "updatePassword_controller()", "role" => "form", "class" => "lost_reset_password"} do %>
                <p class="error_msg" ng-show="update_pass.password_confirmation.$error.passwordVerify"> 
                    Passwords are not equal!
                </p>
            <label>New password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"  ng-minlength="8"  ng-model="updatePasswordForm.password" required="required" class="form-control">
            <span>Minimum 8 Charachters</span>
    <br>
            <label>Re-enter new password</label>

            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation"  ng-minlength="8"  ng-model="updatePasswordForm.password_confirmation" required="required" class="form-control"  password-verify="updatePasswordForm.password" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="reset-submit">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad the template is in anuglarjs html

Comment: Do you mean that you are deploying your angular app outside of Rails with static html? In that case you need to disable the Rails CSRF protection as it relies on server side rendering.

Comment: If you are using token based auth you can accomplish this by removing the sessions middleware.

Comment: initially it was updating password , but i don't know why it stopped .plus i don't know how to remove session middleware